# String overlay using XftDrawString8 flickers when done along with video rendering using eglSwapBuffers

Tags: c, ubuntu, x11, egl

I am rendering video on EGL (X11) using the API eglSwapBuffers. My requirement is to do text overlay on this window. To achieve this I am using XftDrawString8 using Xft library. Though this is working, for some reason the text string flickers. Seems like the string is getting sometimes overlaid before video data and sometimes after video data. Whenever it gets overlaid before it is not seen, but when it is overlaid after it is seen. Can someone help me with a solution to achieve stable text overlay on video data without flickering issue? Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Why not draw the string to the buffer you are swapping in, instead of drawing it directly to the screen?

Comment: We dont have access to buffer pointer that is going to be rendered. The communication from video decoder to video render is through FDs. This is specific to Nvidia Tegra X1.

Comment: You are using eglSwapBuffers, this takes a surface parameter. You can draw on that surface. You have data you get from painting a string to an X11 pixmap. Make a texture from it and draw it on the surface.

Comment: Hello n.m. Can you please elaborate? I am new to X11. Detailed information with APIs will help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: The code is extremely big and distributed for me to put here. Can you please let me know the API which I can try to draw a string on a surface?

Comment: I hear the most accepted way is to (1) draw your text on a bitmap with any client-side text renderer such as Freetype, (2) convert the bitmap to a texture (possibly with GLUtils.texImage2D()?),  and (3) bind the texture to your surface. I have never done it myself.